# count() on where clause from a different table

Tags: sql

I have a search function to search for mysql results depending on their inputs. Now I wanted to include on the `where` clause the count() of likes for the result from a different table.

Like this scenario. `I want to search "Dog" where count(like_id) >= 1.`

The Likes Table that I want to include is: `TABLE_GLOBAL_LIKES`.

The Structure of `TABLE_GLOBAL_LIKES` is:
Fields: `like_id`, `user_id`, `products_id`, `blog_id`.

BOTH `TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS` and `TABLE_GLOBAL_LIKES` has a common field of `products_id` and `blog_id` to associate with.

This is my working query that I want the Likes table to included.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*,
       CASE
           WHEN p.specials_new_products_price > 0.0000
                AND (p.expires_date > Now()
                     OR p.expires_date IS NULL
                     OR p.expires_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                AND p.status != 0 THEN p.specials_new_products_price
           ELSE p.products_price
       END price
FROM ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p
INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id
WHERE MATCH (p.products_name,
             p.products_description) AGAINST ('*".$search_key."*')
  AND p.display_product = '1'
  AND p.products_status = '1' HAVING price <= ".$priceto_key."
  AND price >= ".$pricefrom_key."
ORDER BY p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name
```

I'm a newbie in mysql queries.. Please help.

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, COUNT(l.like_id)
       CASE
           WHEN p.specials_new_products_price > 0.0000
                AND (p.expires_date > Now()
                     OR p.expires_date IS NULL
                     OR p.expires_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                AND p.status != 0 THEN p.specials_new_products_price
           ELSE p.products_price
       END price
FROM ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p
INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id
INNER JOIN ".TABLE_GLOBAL_LIKES." l ON l.blog_id = p.blog_id AND l.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE MATCH (p.products_name,
             p.products_description) AGAINST ('*".$search_key."*')
  AND p.display_product = '1'
  AND p.products_status = '1' HAVING price <= ".$priceto_key."
  AND price >= ".$pricefrom_key."
GROUP BY p.products_id
HAVING COUNT(l.like_id)>0
ORDER BY p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name
```